# cant get do while loop to work right-java

Tags: java, loops, do-while

My problem is that when I run this program I have to press 2 twice, or 3 three times to get the else if statements to run. I have tried switching the input to string and it has the same issues. `(you can ignore all the code except the (sc.nextInt()==1)/(sc.nextInt()==2)/(sc.nextInt()==3))` Those are where I'm having problems. Thanks

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int running = 0;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("(1)Enter hourly employee");
                System.out.println("(2)Enter commissionary employee");
                System.out.println("(3)Terminate program");
                System.out.println();
                if (sc.nextInt()==1){
                    System.out.println("Enter their first name. \n");
                    hour.firstName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their last name. \n");
                    hour.lastName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their Id #. \n");
                    hour.id= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their wage amount. \n");
                    hour.wage= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter how many hours they will be working. \n");
                    hour.hrs= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("employee "+ hour.id + "'s name is " + hour.firstName + " "+ hour.lastName + " their id is "+ hour.id);
                    System.out.println("employee "+ hour.id + "'s wage is " + hour.wage + "$ and will be working "+ hour.hrs +" hours per week.");
                    running++;

                }

                //have to type 2 twice here
                 else if (sc.nextInt()== 2){
                    System.out.println("Enter their first name. \n");
                    com.firstName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their last name. \n");
                    com.lastName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their Id #. \n");
                    com.id= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their base salary. \n");
                    bcom.baseSalary= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their wage commission rate. \n");
                    com.cRate= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their expected gross sales goal. \n");
                    com.gSales= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("employee "+ com.id + "'s name is " + com.firstName + " "+ com.lastName + " their id is "+ com.id);
                    System.out.println("employee "+ com.id + "'s base salary is "+ bcom.baseSalary + "$ their commission rate is \n" + com.cRate + "% and is estimated to make "+ com.gSales +"$ in gross sales.");
                    running++;

                }
                //have to type 3 three times here
                else if (sc.nextInt()== 3)
                {
                    running++;
                }


            }while(running < 1);
```

Comment: Try moving running++ outside the if/else if blocks.

Comment: Every branch of your `if` chain increments `running`. Why should the loop iterate?

Comment: Try: ```int input = sc.nextInt();```, then ```if (input==1)``` ```if (input==2)``` ```if (input==3)```

Comment: @Heron Yang Thank you. duffymo and elliott frisch the running call is to terminate the loop after the if statement is complete. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int running = 0;
            do
            {
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
                System.out.println("(1)Enter hourly employee");
                System.out.println("(2)Enter commissionary employee");
                System.out.println("(3)Terminate program");
                System.out.println();
                int i = sc.nextInt();
                if (i==1){
                    System.out.println("Enter their first name. \n");
                    hour.firstName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their last name. \n");
                    hour.lastName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their Id #. \n");
                    hour.id= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their wage amount. \n");
                    hour.wage= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter how many hours they will be working. \n");
                    hour.hrs= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("employee "+ hour.id + "'s name is " + hour.firstName + " "+ hour.lastName + " their id is "+ hour.id);
                    System.out.println("employee "+ hour.id + "'s wage is " + hour.wage + "$ and will be working "+ hour.hrs +" hours per week.");
                    running++;

                }

                //have to type 2 twice here
                 else if (i== 2){
                    System.out.println("Enter their first name. \n");
                    com.firstName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their last name. \n");
                    com.lastName= sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Enter their Id #. \n");
                    com.id= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their base salary. \n");
                    bcom.baseSalary= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their wage commission rate. \n");
                    com.cRate= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter their expected gross sales goal. \n");
                    com.gSales= sc.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("employee "+ com.id + "'s name is " + com.firstName + " "+ com.lastName + " their id is "+ com.id);
                    System.out.println("employee "+ com.id + "'s base salary is "+ bcom.baseSalary + "$ their commission rate is \n" + com.cRate + "% and is estimated to make "+ com.gSales +"$ in gross sales.");
                    running++;

                }
                //have to type 3 three times here
                else if (i== 3)
                {
                    running++;
                }


            }while(running < 1);
```

because each time u write nextInt(), it will wait for input from User. So, just try to catch 1 input from User, then just check whats the input is.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a 2nd time from sc.nextInt() in your 'else'.
Read once before the 'if', then test the value.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you call `nextInt()`, the process waits and reads your input once.

So, the first `if(sc.nextInt()==1)` reads your input once, and you need to type the second time to reach `else if (sc.nextInt()==2)`.

To solve this, try following structure:

```
int input = sc.nextInt();
if (input == 1) {
} else if (input == 2) {
} else if (input == 3) {
}
```